# Using conditional statement to select different templated matrix class at run-time

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, eigen

I'm working with the templated Matrix class in the Eigen linear algebra library ([link](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMatrixClass.html)).  The Matrix class takes three nominal template parameters:

```
Matrix<type, rows, cols>
```

In the above, an example of `type` is `double`, or `std::complex<double>`.  In addition, `rows` is the number of rows, and `cols` is the number of columns in the Matrix.

As shown by the code below, what I would like to do is use a different templated Matrix class at run-time using a conditional statement.

The first solution that comes to mind might be to use void pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <complex>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()

{  
    // this flag is set at run-time, but it is only set here
    // in the code as an example
    int create_complex = 1;
    void *M;

        if(create_complex)
    {
        Matrix<std::complex<double>,3,3> m0;
        M = &m0;
    }
    else
    {
        Matrix<double,3,3> m0;
        M = &m0;
    }
    // de-reference pointer here and use it    

 return 0;
}
```

Although this code compiles, the `void *M` pointer needs to be explicitly de-referenced before use.  This is inconvenient, since I then have to write different code blocks for the same program logic.

I am wondering if there is something similar to polymorphism that might be applied here, where I don't have to use void pointers.

Comment: The `create_complex` flag is not known at compile time.  I am simply using `create_complex` as an example.

Comment: Do you mind using `boost::variant` ? I'd try very hard to avoid being in your situation (maybe a little more background would help us help you), but if I must, I'd go with it.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Sure, I would like to use `boost::variant`. I've used the boost library before, but I can't say that I've heard of that particular container.  It seems very interesting.  How might I use it?

Comment: Boost variant will allow you to define a type that can store *either* a Matrix<double, n, m> or a Matrix<complex<double>, n, m>. This way, you don't need a pointer to void. Again, there may be a better way to write the code.

Comment: Thanks, Alexandre C.  Boost variant is indeed very nice.  Hooray for boost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should templatize your method too:

```
template<class T>
my_main() { 

   Matrix<T,3,3> m0;

   // ...


}
```

**UPDATE**

Or you can define your class

```
#ifndef CREATE_COMPLEX
    typedef double MyClass;
#else
    typedef std::complex<double> MyClass;
#endif

main() { 

   Matrix<MyClass,3,3> m0;

   // ...


}
```

you can switch these definitions with preprocessor definition.

Comment: Sure, the method could be templatized, and then I wouldn't have to deal with the void pointers.  Thanks, Dims.

Answer (score 2):

> This is inconvenient

If you read "inconvenient" as "illegal", then you're spot on.

The local variables are destroyed when their scope ends (i.e. the closing `}`), so you're left with a dangling pointer. So you'll run into undefined behavior when trying to de-reference it.

There's no easy way to do this, because `Matrix<std::complex<double>,3,3>` and `Matrix<double,3,3>` are completely unrelated classes. I'll say it again. **They are completely unrelated classes**.

An alternative is that `Matrix` has a base type and you have a pointer to that, but then you'd need dynamic allocation. Something like:

```
BaseMatrix* m;
if ()
    m = new Matrix<std::complex<double>,3,3>;
else 
    m = new Matrix<double,3,3>;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own function as a template based on the matrix type and call different versions of that in the conditionals.

This is the only way because templates are for generating code at *compile* time. You *must* generate all code paths at compile time and then just select one of them.